# Refresh a directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm rather new to Angular, so I'm not sure if "refreshing the directive" is worded correctly. I'm building a quiz in Angular and use [djds4rce's angular-socialshare](https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare) to display a twitter button.

edit: sorry for the lack of info earlier. Here's more code:

edit edit: Okay, this obviously has to do either with the angular-socialshare plugin OR the twitter button. When I do this to the twitter button:

```
<a twitter data-text="{{score}}"></a>
```

I see in my Developer tools in Chrome that it correctly shows the score of the user. However when I click the link, all of a sudden the text is back to "0".

**HTML**

I get a list from an api. Each element (I call it premier) of that list has both a name and a 'correct' attribute.

```
<button ng-click="validateClick(premier, $index)" 
class="btn btn-default btn-game" 
data-correct="@{{premier.correct}}" 
ng-class="{'disabled btn-danger': premier.isPremier, 'disabled btn-success': premier.isRandom}" 
ng-repeat="premier in premiers" 
ng-disabled="gameOver" 
ng-bind="premier.name">
```

And I display the score for the user:

```
<span class="score" ng-bind="score"> </span>/70
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

In my Angular controller I have a variable called score

```
premierApp.controller('premierController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.score = 0;

//so if this correct value = "premier", Game Over! if it = "random", then the user gets a point
$scope.validateClick = function (premier, index) {
    if (premier.correct == "premier") {
        premier.isPremier = true;
        $scope.gameOver = true;
        $scope.stopGame();
    } else {
        premier.isRandom = true;
        $scope.score++;
    }
}
```

and I'm using a directive to display a tweet button so the user can tweet his score:

directive:

```
premierApp.directive('tweetbutton', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'html_templates/premiers_tweetbutton.html',
    };
});
```

and the templateurl is this:

```
<a twitter
    data-lang="en"
    data-size="medium"
    data-text="{{score}}">
</a>
```

Right now the text (data-text) of the twitter button remains "0" (the standard value when I declared the variable in my Controller).

**How can I update the directive to display the new score that my app calculated?**

Comment: Yes, so when a user answers a question correct, I add one to the score. I even show the score to the user simply by {{ score }} and it works correctly. However for some reason the directive keeps showing "0"

Comment: Thats because the library doesn't support that behaviour. take a look to the code. Look this line: https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare/blob/master/angular-socialshare.js#L112..

Moving forward on issues for that library.. 
https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare/issues/17..
So. No it doesn't support double binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might need to do:

```
$scope.$apply()
```

in your controller function but if I could see a plunkr or some more code that would be helpful

make a plunkr, lets see everything, I'd like to know what element your directive is attached to. directives will "refresh" automatically if the value of that $scope is changed. again, making a plunkr will help, I don't know how everything is looking for you.

**UPDATE**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6LSXhOV1r8c4HQeDq0L?p=preview

Try this:

Your directive:

```
premierApp.directive('tweetbutton', function($compile) {
   return {
       scope: { score: "@score" },
       templateUrl: 'premiers_tweetbutton.html'
   };
});
```

And in the view

```
<div tweetbutton score="{{score}}"></div>
```

Comment: what element do you have 'tweetbutton' applied to? btw, it is common in directives to name that is 'tweetButton" instead and then reference it in the view as <div tweet-button> @JelleVandeVliet

Comment: mkay I'll make a plunkr for you... brb getting a red bull and snickers

Comment: @PatrickLawler Hi Patrick, I applied it to a div. I edited my OP once more, it is updating the score. But when I click the tweet button, it just shows "0"

Comment: take a look at the directive in this plunker, can you give this a shot with your code and see if that helps? If not it looks like it could be the problem @rahpuser is talking about, you should still be able to work around it though.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6LSXhOV1r8c4HQeDq0L?p=preview

Comment: if you open up developer tools in your browser and look at data-text, the value is updating in that plunkr, let me know if that worked for you @JelleVandeVliet I'm curious to find out if it's the socialshare library or just an issue of passing the scope to your directive correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment @PatrickLawler. I really appreciate your help! Your plnkr is indeed the same as I had, but it was/is a problem with the socialshare lib.

Comment: :/ thats too bad... my directive is slightly different than yours though... did you try the method I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

you are not telling us how and where your app calculates the new value.

angularjs provides two way data binding, so if you programatically change your $scope.score = 1, it will magically "re-render" the new value.

then in your controller you can have something like

```
premierApp.controller('premierController', function ($scope, $http) {

   $scope.score = 0;

   $scope.functionCalledByUserAction = function () {
     var newScore = $scope.score++; //replace this your code here to set a newScore
     $scope.score = newScore;
   }
```

So in your views if you do something like

```html
<button ng-click="functionCalledByUserAction()">Set new score</button>
```

your score should start changing.

By the way you do not need a directive for this, you can just use

```html
<div ng-include="html_templates/premiers_tweetbutton.html"></div>
```

to bring your partial in your view